# uniroot() function in source code does not work with modification; Could not figure out the error

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, purrr, uniroot

I was trying to find out coordinates of the intersection of two curves in R. The input data are coordinates of empirical points from the two curves. My solution is to use the function [curve_intersect()](https://rdrr.io/github/andrewheiss/reconPlots/src/R/curve_intersect.R). I need to do this for 2000 replications (i.e., 2000 pairs of curves). So I put the data in two lists. Each list contains 1000 data frames with x & y coordinates of one curve in each data frame.

Here is my data: [data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yhshw1p96odf8w7/AAAPwfyrag5BTBN02t5WtOpRa?dl=0)

Below are the code that I used.

```
threshold_or1 <- map2_df(recall_or1_4, precision_or1_4,
                         ~curve_intersect(.x, .y, empirical = TRUE, domain = NULL))

# recall_or_4 is a list of 2000 data frames. Each data frame 
# |contains coordinates from curve #1. 

# precision_or_4 is a list of 2000 data frames. Each data frame 
# |contains coordinates from curve #2.
```

I got this error message below.

```
Error in uniroot(function(x) curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x), c(min(curve1$x),  : f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Since the function curve_intersect() can be successfully applied to some individual data frames from the two lists. I ran the following code in order to see exactly which pair of data frames made the process fail.

```
test <- for (i in 1:2000){
            curve_intersect(recall_or1_4[[i]], precision_or1_4[[i]], empirical = TRUE, domain = NULL)
            print(paste("i=",i))}
```

Then, I got the following message, which means that the process ran successfully until it reaches the data pair #460. So I checked that individual data pair.

```
[1] "i= 457"
[1] "i= 458"
[1] "i= 459"
Error in uniroot(function(x) curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x), c(min(curve1$x),  : f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

I plotted data pairs #460.

```
test1 <- precision_or1_4[[460]] %>% mutate(statistics = 'precision')
test2 <- recall_or1_4[[460]] %>% mutate(statistics = 'recall')
test3 <- rbind(test1, test2)
test3 <- test3 %>% mutate(statistics = as.factor(statistics))
curve_test3 <- ggplot(test3, aes(x = x, y = y))+
        geom_line(aes(colour = statistics))
curve_test3
```

[Find coordinates of the intersection point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgN3o.png)

I then went to modify the source code of curve_intersect(). The original source code is

```
    curve_intersect <- function(curve1, curve2, empirical=TRUE, domain=NULL) {
        if (!empirical & missing(domain)) {
                stop("'domain' must be provided with non-empirical curves")
        }
        
        if (!empirical & (length(domain) != 2 | !is.numeric(domain))) {
                stop("'domain' must be a two-value numeric vector, like c(0, 10)")
        }
        
        if (empirical) {
                # Approximate the functional form of both curves
                curve1_f <- approxfun(curve1$x, curve1$y, rule = 2)
                curve2_f <- approxfun(curve2$x, curve2$y, rule = 2)
                
                # Calculate the intersection of curve 1 and curve 2 along the x-axis
                point_x <- uniroot(function(x) curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x),
                                   c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x)))$root
                
                # Find where point_x is in curve 2
                point_y <- curve2_f(point_x)
        } else {
                # Calculate the intersection of curve 1 and curve 2 along the x-axis
                # within the given domain
                point_x <- uniroot(function(x) curve1(x) - curve2(x), domain)$root
                
                # Find where point_x is in curve 2
                point_y <- curve2(point_x)
        }
        
        return(list(x = point_x, y = point_y))
}
```

I modified the `uniroot()` part from the third if statement. Instead of using `c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x))` as an argument of `uniroot()`, I used `lower = -100000000, upper = 100000000`. The modified function is

```
curve_intersect_tq <- function(curve1, curve2, empirical=TRUE, domain=NULL) {
        if (!empirical & missing(domain)) {
                stop("'domain' must be provided with non-empirical curves")
        }
        
        if (!empirical & (length(domain) != 2 | !is.numeric(domain))) {
                stop("'domain' must be a two-value numeric vector, like c(0, 10)")
        }
        
        if (empirical) {
                # Approximate the functional form of both curves
                curve1_f <- approxfun(curve1$x, curve1$y, rule = 2)
                curve2_f <- approxfun(curve2$x, curve2$y, rule = 2)
                
                # Calculate the intersection of curve 1 and curve 2 along the x-axis
                point_x <- uniroot(function(x) curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x),
                                   lower = -100000000, upper = 100000000)$root
                
                # Find where point_x is in curve 2
                point_y <- curve2_f(point_x)
        } else {
                # Calculate the intersection of curve 1 and curve 2 along the x-axis
                # within the given domain
                point_x <- uniroot(function(x) curve1(x) - curve2(x), domain)$root
                
                # Find where point_x is in curve 2
                point_y <- curve2(point_x)
        }
        
        return(list(x = point_x, y = point_y))
}
```

I tried to change the values of `lower =, upper =` arguments. It did not work. I got the same error message as shown below.

```
curve_intersect_tq(recall_or1_4[[460]], precision_or1_4[[460]], empirical = TRUE, domain = NULL)

Error in uniroot(function(x) curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x), c(min(curve1$x),  : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

I also tried to use `possibly(fun, NA)` from the tidyverse package hoping that the process can run even with an error message. It did not work when I used

(1) `possibly(curve_intersect(), NA)` or
(2) `possibly(uniroot(), NA)`

The same error message appeared.

Why do I have the error message? What could be possible solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a little late to the party, but here's why your code still fails and what you could do, depending on what you want to get out of your analysis:

First of all, **the reason why your code fails**, even after adaptation, is that you are merely telling `uniroot` to search a wider window in `x`. However, **the underlying curves will never intersect** - there just isn't any `curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x) == 0` to be found.

From the doc of `uniroot`:

> "The function values at the endpoints must be of opposite signs (or zero), for extendInt="no", the default."

In the original `curve_intersect` implementation, `uniroot` is searching the x-interval that is defined in your data (that's the `c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x))`). In your alteration, you're telling it to search in the x interval `[-100000000, 100000000]`. You could as well have set `extendInt = "yes"`, but it wouldn't change anything.
The problem doesn't lie in the search interval, it lies with `approxfun`!

`approxfun` merely helps you by *interpolating* empirical data between points. Outside of the data you pass in, the returned function wouldn't know what to do.
`approxfun` allows you to specify explicit values for `y` which should be returned outside the empirically defined window (with its params `yleft`/`yright`) or lets you set a `rule` for each side.
In the code you posted above, `rule = 2` decides that "the value at the closest data extreme is used". So, `approxfun` does not *extrapolate* the data you pass in. It only extends the known.

We can plot how `curve1_f` and `curve2_f` will extend outside the empirically defined x-interval into infinity:

```
tibble(
    x = seq(0, 1, by = 0.001),
    curve1_approxed = curve1_f(x),
    curve2_approxed = curve2_f(x)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("curve"), names_to = "curve", values_to = "y") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = curve)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x)), color = "grey75")
```

[image: approxfun outside empirically defined x interval]

---

So, now to **what you can do to get your code to not crash**:
(spoiler: it pretty much depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your project)

1. **accept** that there is no intersection in the observed limits of your data.
   If you don't want to make any assumptions, I'd suggest you wrap your mapped function in a `tryCatch` statement and let it fail where the out-of-the-box solution doesn't give you any results. Let's run this for the part of your list that previously made the whole thing crash:

```
threshold_or1.fix1 <- map2_df(
  recall_or1_4, precision_or1_4,
  ~tryCatch({
    curve_intersect(.x, .y, empirical = TRUE, domain = NULL)
  }, error = function(e){
    return(tibble(.rows = 1))
  }),
  .id = "i"
)
```

Now, there is just a NA row when `curve_intersect` isn't able to give you a result.

```
threshold_or1.fix1[459:461,]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  i          x      y
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 459    0.116  0.809
2 460   NA     NA    
3 461    0.264  0.773
```

2. try to **extrapolate** your data with a linear model
   In this case, we'll use a custom `curve_intersect`-function. Let's wrap the problematic `uniroot` call in a `tryCatch` and if no root can be found, we'll fit a `lm` for each curve and let `uniroot` find an intersection on the fitted linears.
   That might or might not make sense in the light of your experiment, so I'll let you be the judge here. And obviously you can use other models than the simplistic `lm` if your data is more complex than that...
   Just to visualize this approach vs the default:

```
tibble(
    x = seq(-1, 2, by = 0.001),
    curve1_approxed = curve1_f(x),
    curve2_approxed = curve2_f(x),
    curve1_lm = predict(lm(y ~ x, data = curve1), newdata = tibble(x = x)),
    curve2_lm = predict(lm(y ~ x, data = curve2), newdata = tibble(x = x))
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("curve"), names_to = "curve", values_to = "y") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = curve)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x)), color = "grey75")
```

[image: approxfun vs lm outside empirically defined x interval]
You see, where `approxfun` "fails", with `lm` we make that assumption that we can extrapolate linearly and find an intersection around `x = 1.27` outside of your observed frame.

To go for that second approach and include an extrapolation with `lm` in our search, you could throw together something like this:
(here, too, only the third `if` is edited.)

```
curve_intersect_custom <- function(curve1, curve2, empirical=TRUE, domain=NULL) {
  if (!empirical & missing(domain)) {
    stop("'domain' must be provided with non-empirical curves")
  }
  
  if (!empirical & (length(domain) != 2 | !is.numeric(domain))) {
    stop("'domain' must be a two-value numeric vector, like c(0, 10)")
  }
  
  if (empirical) {
    
    return(
      tryCatch({
        # Approximate the functional form of both curves
        curve1_f <- approxfun(curve1$x, curve1$y, rule = 2)
        curve2_f <- approxfun(curve2$x, curve2$y, rule = 2)
        
        # Calculate the intersection of curve 1 and curve 2 along the x-axis
        point_x <- uniroot(
          f = function(x) curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x),
          interval = c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x))
        )$root
        
        # Find where point_x is in curve 2
        point_y <- curve2_f(point_x)
        
        return(list(x = point_x, y = point_y, method = "approxfun"))
        
      }, error = function(e) {
        tryCatch({
          curve1_lm_f <- function(x) predict(lm(y ~ x, data = curve1), newdata = tibble(x = x))
          curve2_lm_f <- function(x) predict(lm(y ~ x, data = curve2), newdata = tibble(x = x))
          
          point_x <- uniroot(
            f = function(x) curve1_lm_f(x) - curve2_lm_f(x),
            interval = c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x)),
            extendInt = "yes"
          )$root
          
          point_y <- curve2_lm_f(point_x)
          
          return(list(x = point_x, y = point_y, method = "lm"))
          
        }, error = function(e) {
          return(list(x = NA_real_, y = NA_real_, method = NA_character_))
        })
      })
    )
    
    
  } else {
    # Calculate the intersection of curve 1 and curve 2 along the x-axis
    # within the given domain
    point_x <- uniroot(function(x) curve1(x) - curve2(x), domain)$root
    
    # Find where point_x is in curve 2
    point_y <- curve2(point_x)
  }
  
  return(list(x = point_x, y = point_y))
}
```

For your problematic list elements, this now tries to extrapolate with the naively fitted `lm` model:

```
threshold_or1.fix2 <- map2_df(
    recall_or1_4, precision_or1_4,
    ~curve_intersect_custom(.x, .y, empirical = TRUE, domain = NULL),
    .id = "i"
)

threshold_or1.fix2[459:461,]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  i         x     y method   
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 459   0.116 0.809 approxfun
2 460   1.27  0.813 lm       
3 461   0.264 0.773 approxfun
```

Hope this helps a little in understanding and fixing your issue :)